# How to change ticks in matplotlib when saving to a figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, figure

I have this code to save four plots into a figure:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,18))
for i in range(4):
    labels = [...]
    x = ...
    y = ...
    plt.subplot(221+i)
    plt.title('Title here')
    plt.xlabel('x-axis label')
    plt.ylabel('y-axis label')
    plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
plt.savefig('fig.png', format='png')
```

Anyway I'd like to replace ticks on x-axis with labels. I tried `plt.xticks(labels)`, but it doesn't work.

**update**
I finally managed that thanks to solution given by Lev. The full code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,18))
for i in range(4):
    labels = [...]
    x = ...
    y = ...
    plt.subplot(221+i)
    plt.title('Title here')
    plt.xlabel('x-axis label')
    plt.ylabel('y-axis label')
    plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
    plt.xticks(range(len(x)), labels)
plt.savefig('fig.png', format='png')
```

Comment: Your question doesn't specify how you want to change the ticks. Is it the tick size/shape or the tick labels? The clearer your question the better the answers will be.

Comment: Labels, sorry. I'll update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks), you can set the labels as follows:

```
plt.xticks(locations, labels)
```

If you don't want to change the tick locations, you can do:

```
plt.xticks(plt.xticks()[0], labels)
```

Comment: I'm not interested to change the tick location, so the second instruction would be great. Anyway, I tried to add that instruction before and after the plot() command, but never changed. Where am I supposed to add that?

Comment: @f_ficarola After the `plot`, because the `plot` can adjust the ticks itself. Can you update the question with your code?

Comment: Tried both, but it doesn't seem to work. Anyway, I've updated my code.

Comment: @f_ficarola It works fine for me. Maybe the problem is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @f_ficarola We'll be happy to help if you edit your question so that it provides a reproducible example.

Comment: I was able to manage that thanks to your solution, Lev. I updated my code! Thank you again.